# Google Api:: Error: invalid_scope

Tags: php

i am using google api OAuth2 for signing into gmail account when for gmail sign in i go for auth then i got the error: Error: invalid_scope

This app hasn't been verified to access: {invalid = [https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts]} Please contact the developer for assistance. Are you the developer? If this project needs these scopes, sign in to an account with access to edit your project and try again. If not, contact the developer for help.
Please help regarding this where i am wrong.

Comment: add some codes ............

Comment: this is not code fault i have create clientId, clientSecret from my different gmail account on different domain there is running fine

Comment: check redirect uri (callback url)

Comment: $client = new \Google_Client(); $client -> setApplicationName('Gmail Contact'); $client -> setClientid($google_client_id); $client -> setClientSecret($google_client_secret); $client -> setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri); $client -> setAccessType('offline');

Comment: $client->setScopes(array( 'googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email';, 'apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/';, 'apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/';, 'apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/';, 'google.com/m8/feeds/';, 'google.com/m8/feeds/user/';, 'googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly';, 'googleapis.com/auth/calendar'; ));

Comment: this is from google verification end i have fill api verification form and got this message:

Comment: Thank you for submitting the verification request. A member of our team will review the details and get back to you as soon as possible. This typically takes between 3 and 7 business days, but in some cases it may take longer.

In the meantime, you can test your application by adding your test accounts to this Google group (risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps). This will enable you to request sensitive scopes specifically for these test accounts.

Comment: Please note you can only request sensitive scopes for other accounts (not in risky-access-by-unreviewed-apps) after the verification process is complete.

Thank you for your patience while your request is reviewed.

Sincerely,

Google Cloud Platform/API Trust & Safety

Answer (score 1):

Seems they are certain scopes that require you to explicitly seek google verification in order to perform Oauth dance. See related posts below

[Error: invalid_scope - This app hasn't been verified to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329890/error-invalid-scope-this-app-hasnt-been-verified-to-access)

https://www.cloudsponge.com/blog/google-oauth-reviews/

Answer (score -1):

Scopes are like when a site that logs in through Facebook, and Facebook asks 'This site would like permission to: get your email address (scope), access friends list (another scope) etc.

You must send the scope you need in your request headers.

Comment: Thanks for reply
but i am using google api and doing login by gmail id i have define all scopes into google api library where i am calling access contact url

Comment: this is not code fault i have create clientId, clientSecret from my different gmail account on different domain there is running fine

Comment: I take it you have an API key etc for this new account?

Comment: $client = new \Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName('Gmail Contact');
$client -> setClientid($google_client_id);
$client -> setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$client -> setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri);
$client -> setAccessType('offline');

Comment: $client->setScopes(array(
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/groups/',
 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/alias/',
 'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/user/',
 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/',
 'https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/user/',
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar'
));

Comment: Have you gave permission for these scopes in google settings? One of them isn't being allowed. Try taking them out and adding them back in one at a time until you find it.

Comment: where i can gave these permission for these scopes ?

Comment: Have a look here at all the available scopes. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes

Comment: All the scopes you need for gmail have the word gmail in them. The scopes in your code are for different google services!

Comment: @Vinod, thank you for your feedback above.  It wasn't clear based on google's documentation that the scope has to be defined using the entire url.